# 404 (Not Found) when trying to route to the index with mongodb and nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on an app for a portfolio that works as sort of a video game companion but I can't seem to get it to connect to the mongo server.

My code seems to work as it says that the connection is successful when I run the server.js in node as this is what my terminal says.

> (node:45137) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= >4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if >using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com >/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
>   App running on port 27017!
>   Mongoose connection successful.

However when I try put it on localhost it fails

> GET http://localhost:27017/ 404 (Not Found)

This is my server code with the routes inside it.

I've already double checked to make sure all the styles and javascripts needed are linked correctly but still no good.

```js
// Dependencies
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
var request = require("request");

// Set mongoose to leverage built in JavaScript ES6 Promises
mongoose.Promise = Promise;


// Initialize Express
var app = express();

// Use morgan and body parser with our app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

// Make public a static dir
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Database configuration with mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/usersdb");
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Show any mongoose errors
db.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", error);
});

// Once logged in to the db through mongoose, log a success message
db.once("open", function() {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});


//routes

app.get('/', function(req, res, next, error){
 // Log any errors
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Or send the doc to the browser as a json object
    else {
    res.render("index",{ title: 'Express' });
      }
});




// Listen on port 27107
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 27017, function() {
  console.log("App running on port 27017!");
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set wrong signature for the router handler, instead of `app.get('/', function(req, res, next, error){` , you need to use `app.get('/', function(req, res, next){`, without `error` param, which if occur should be on first place, and when error param occur this handler will be an error middleware.

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks so much!